# How to use Flask's render_template() standalone without Flask app

Tags: flask, celery, jinja2

I'm contributing to a Flask app which uses `render_template`. However the app also makes use of Celery for scheduling async tasks. These tasks need to render some templates, but because they are executed by Celery asynchronously they do not have the Flask's app context, and I cannot use `render_template` like I would normally do inside a Flask controller (eg. @route(...)).
So, how can I use `render_template` if I don't have a Flask context?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could achieve this by [manually pushing an app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context) then using Flask's `render_template_string` function:

```
>>> from flask import Flask, render_template_string
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> with app.app_context():
>>>     render_template_string('I love {{fruit}}', fruit='apple')
'I love apple'
```

Of course, instead of providing a string as the first argument to `render_template_string` you *could* open a template file, and pass `fh.read()`

Depending on your implementation you could probably use `render_template` here, although this would return a `Response` object.

How you deal with the return value is then up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to **render a template**, you can just use **jinja2** module which is already imported by Flask.

```py
    >>> from jinja2 import Template
    >>> tpl = Template("I love {{ fruit }}")
    >>> print(tpl.render(fruit="apple"))
    'I love apple'
```